# Mouse in lubuntu have a problem

Tags: lubuntu, mouse

I'm currently using Lubuntu and I like it, but I have a problem with the mouse pointer.

I'm an android developer and I use eclipse. When I drag a button container in Eclipse then my I get 2 pointers on the screen at the same time. I don't know what to do.

Comment: I know this is a late time to be responding but I'm going through old questions and seeing what I can help get resolved. I've seen this behavior before but only when I was accessing the computer via remote - specifically with VNC. Is that the case here or are you physically at the machine? If you have resolved this could you let us know how so that we can add it to the great store of knowledge that is AskUbuntu? :D